# Redirect links using .htaccess file

Tags: php, htaccess

I have a site with a lot of links that look like `/click.php_id=602_from=139_to=42_url=1.html`. I'd like to setup a redirect using `.htaccess` file(s) to have links that look like `/click.php?id=602&from=139&to=42&url=1`. But how would I do that?

Comment: Setup rewrite rules. For examples see [.htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory)

Comment: please help me.

Comment: No. What have you actually tried? Did you read the [apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) on mod_rewrite? Did you even try to come up with rewrite rules that match your problem? Please spend some time to read [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I've never used .htaccess (don't forget to permit .htaccess to actually rewrite requests), but in Apache's conf it would be more or less like this:

```
RewriteRule /click.php_id=([0-9]+)_from=([0-9]+)_to=([0-9]+)_url=([0-9]+)\.html$ /click.php?id=$1&from=$2&to=$3&url=$4
```

you need to check my syntax, I just typed this from memory

Comment: it doesnt work(

Comment: thanks a lot, all good   RewriteRule ^click\.php_id=([0-9]+)_from=([0-9]+)_to=([0-9]+)_url=([0-9]+)\.html$ /click\.php?id=$1&from=$2&to=$3&url=$4 [R=301,L]
its true

Comment: I see, because a .htaccess is always in a folder, the leading slash in `/click.php' should be dropped..  One is never too old to learn.